# How do I burn the Ubuntu ISO to a CD-RW in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, iso-image

What should I choose if I want to burn a Ubuntu ISO to the CD so that I can boot Ubuntu from CD on start-up?

Should I choose treat the CD like a USB which is save, edit, delete files at any time or like a CD which after burning a file cannot be edited or removed?

Comment: The later versions of Ubuntu require a DVD, not a CD. What version are you trying to create a disc for? What program are you using to burn the ISO? You may want to take a look at [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows).

Comment: For version 14.04.1 and im not using a program do I have to?

Comment: You will need to burn the ISO to a DVD for 14.04. Take a look at the instructions. Try the instructions at the link before downloading an image burning program.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of those options are correct, because both will simply take the .ISO and burn it to the disk as if it were a regular file. You need to burn as an image. Fortunately this is very easy in Windows 7; just right click the file and select "Burn Disk Image" as shown below:
[image]

As others have said, the latest version of Ubuntu will not fit into a CD so you must use a DVD.

Comment: Remember there has to be a blank CD in the drive when you press this, and most Ubuntu ISO's will require a DVD. If the file is larger than 700MB, it needs a DVD.